# Is it possible to use "DDR Xccella Mode" when connecting an external RAM to the STM32?

Tags: stm32, spi, sram

MCU: [STM32H7A3ZIT6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h7a3zi.pdf)

RAM: [APS12808L-3OBMx](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1127/APM_PSRAM_OPI_Xccela_APS12808L_3OBMx_v1_1b_PKG-1954845.pdf)

This ram supports "DDR Xccela mode", where it transfers data on the rising and falling edge of the clock.

I'm fairly sure my MCU supports the standard octospi interface, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to get the double data rate. The MCU datasheet doesn't say anything about Xccela mode, but it does support some other modes "hyperram?" which I believe also transfers data on the rising and falling edge of the clock.

Comment: You should find the details in the MCU reference manual. Have you looked there for an answer?

Comment: "it transfers data on the rising and falling edge of the clock" - that's just DDR mode. What makes "Xccella" different?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: maybe.

"Xccela" mode appears to be generally the same as Hyperbus, which that STM device supports (DDR clock, CMD+32 bit address / 6-byte header). However, they *are* different, and the Xccela consortium isn't saying exactly how. More about this below.

Check with ST apps engineering to ascertain if that Xccela part is supported. Failing that, ST specifically supports Hyperbus. So if you can't get an answer from them on Xccela, go with a Hyperbus part instead.

A business note. Hyperbus is promoted by Infineon (Cypress) and Spansion and is included in the JEDEC xSPI standard as an open document. Xccella is promoted by Micron, and while it is backward-compatable with JEDEC xSPI, it isn't included in the standard itself.

MORE: With some digging I did find at least a couple of differences between the protocols, from here: https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/ug6766.pdf

- Xccela supports byte-aligned data. Hyperbus does not (16-bit align only.)
- Hyperbus uses a differential clock pair (optional, but recommended for clocks above 100MHz.) Xccela clock is single-ended.